# How do I remove this wall plate with no visible screws?

Tags: coaxial-cable, cover, phone-wiring

I'm amazed how complicated this wall plate is to remove. It is made of plastic and accommodates a phone jack and a coaxial cable. Please see the images that accompany this question.

I've searched it thoroughly and there are no tabs anywhere on the face or edges to press in. There are no screws.

I've pulled on it pretty hard, hoping that it would pop off, but if I pulled any harder it surely would break. Of course, I had the coaxial off while I tried to remove the plate.

The brand name on the phone jack part is "KRONE". Has anyone seen a wall plate like this? If so, how do you remove it?

I have to say, I'm absolutely blown away by how ridiculously difficult this is. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: They typically call these "quick port" nowadays. The jacks (sometimes called keystones) you see are modular and the wall plate is almost certainly not made by the company that made the keystone.

Comment: Complicated? No.  Obvious? No.  Easy? Yes!

Comment: Top screw cover says ADC, Phone jack says Krone, Same company since 2004: https://www.adckcl.com/in/en/productsandservices/carrier/Accessnet/

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Hah! Like everything DIY!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's not complicated, you just haven't used one before.

I use ones like it all day long.

The screws are hidden under the little rectangular plastic bits at top and bottom. Typically you push one end in and pry the other one sideways until it pops up. Sometimes you just have to pry one end until it bends far enough to release, but usually it slips under the other end if you push the other end in.

Here's one fresh out of the bag, with one opaque and one clear plastic screw cover (it comes with two of each, the clear ones normally have labels under them, which hides the screw)
[image: Keystone jack]

OK, the other two pictures I tried to take came out even worse. The two screw covers have a lip that keeps them in place, but they are flexible so that they can bend to allow insertion/ release, and there's extra space so they can be pushed back at the end to slide sideways (on most of them, this is a design cribbed from Ma Bell back when there was only one Ma Bell.)

Comment: A paper clip or similar can be stuck into the tiny hole at one end of the cover to help with removal.

Comment: Never having seen one before that would have been my first guess anyway--the little hole strongly suggested it.

Comment: Why would anyone want to hide the screw heads? The stupid little panels that cover them look way worse.

Comment: To require a certain level of knowledge (competence would be nice, but hardly guaranteed) before a person can get in and make things worse, rather than attracting wayward screwdrivers in the hands of users (the L is silent.) Ma Bell came up with the design when Ma Bell owned and maintained her wires all the way into your house or business.